# Complete/Submit form then redirect to PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

I have a form that a user fill out. In the form I have 4 payment categories: $10, $20, $30, $40 that are displayed as check boxes. What I am trying to do is, when the user checks one of the check boxes and then submits the forms he is is then views a PayPal button. When clicked he is redirected to a PayPal page. For example, If I check $10 check box then I am redirected to a PayPal page with the $10. My problem right now is that I am not able to redirect. When I submit I do not see the PayPal button. Has someone dealt with something like this before? Thanks. 
Here is a basic code:
Page input:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="$10" >
<input type="checkbox" name="2" value="$20" >
<input type="checkbox" name="3" value="$30" >
<input type="checkbox" name="4" value="$40" >
```

Page submit:

```
// category     
        $category = $_POST['category']; 

        if ($category == "1") {
            $show = "1, $10";
            $pay = "$10";
        } else if ($category == "2") {
            $show = "2, $20";
            $pay = "$20";
        } else if ($category == "3") {
            $show = "3, $30";
            $pay = "$30";
        } else if ($category == "4") {
            $show = "4, $40";
            $pay = "$40";}

 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="form2"    method="post" target="_blank" style="padding:0px">
            2. Pay by Credit Card (PayPal)
            <? include ("pages/categories/$category.php");  ?>
            </form>
```

And then category pages:
I have a folder called "categories" inside this page I have 4 pages with these 4 payment categories. On each page I have pasted a PayPal button code as follows.

Comment: Please post the code that you have so we can assist.

Comment: I just posted some of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML and PHP don't match. Your form has the name of the inputs as 1, 2, 3, 4. Your PHP is looking for a form field name "category".

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="1">
```